# How to add only 1 value in a list in the Update function when a GameObject is active for many frames

Tags: unity, c#, support

In my C# script, I get the active gameobjects during play mode. Those gameObjects that are active are:

1- First, I get the ones that the application has selected randomly 2- and then after the first ones get disabled (setActive(false)), I get the selected gameObjects which are those that the user has pressed using their button.

So basically the application is: The user hears a sound being played (here I set active the gameObject that has that sound) and then after some frames, the sound gets disabled and then the user needs to press a button in screen to make a choice depending on the sound (here I set active the gameObject that has the button) and then I disable that game object after some frames.

Now every time one of those gameObjects gets selected, I try to add to my list some sort of value (lets say 1 in this case). But what happens is that I only manage to add the value in the Update() function but in this function I do not get only 1 value added in the list every time I get the first gameObject selected but because it updates every frame, this value gets added for like 125 times in the list until this gameObject gets diselected and the next gameObject (the one that holds the button) get active.

```
  if (DogSelected.activeSelf && NoCarSelected.activeSelf)
    {
        enable = true;

        if (enable)
        {
            DogLionSelected.Add(0);
            NoCarCarSelected.Add(0);



            enable = false;
        }

        if (DogPressed.activeSelf && NoCarPressed.activeSelf )
        {
            enable = true;

            if (enable)
            {
                string[] data = new string[] { scene.name.ToString(), "0", "0", "0", "0", "1" }; orientationStringWriter.Write(string.Join(delimiter, data) + "\n");
                DogLionPressed.Add(0);
                NoCarCarPressed.Add(0);
                PrimaryCorrectIncorrect.Add(1);


                enable = false;
            }

        }
```

Ideally, I would want to:

1- Hear the sound (gameObject is active) => add only 1 value in list until the gameObject is deselected. 2- Then do the same thing for the gameObjects that hold the button. So when that gets selected = > add only one value in the other list until this gameObject is deselected. Then do the same process 72 times (because the number of trials in this application is 72).

Can anyone give me any advice how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: This description is currently very confusing to try to understand. And your code does not make much sense - `enable = true;` followed by `if(enable) { }` is the same as just deleting the if condition and always executing its contents unconditionally (unless `enable` is doing something unusual) Try separating out your description of "Here is the gameplay experience I want my player to have" from "here is how I have set up my scene and structured the actions of my code to try to accomplish this." Be sure to show us enough of your code & context that we can reproduce the problem in a new project.

Comment: Hi @DMGregory Thank for your answer. I made this work and now I am trying to put the data into excel file. I wrote this question here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/write-data-from-list-to-csv-file.643561/#post-4313491 Any advice will be very helpful

Comment: If you solved your.problem, please post your solution as an answer.